# MassTransit 2.10.0 cause LockRecursionException

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I'm running into an issue where LockRecursionException is thrown (occasionally) when sending a message in MassTransit via RabbitMq.

> System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Write lock may not be acquired with read lock held. This pattern is prone to deadlocks

The exception is raised in the class `MassTransit.Transports.DefaultConnectionPolicy`, and it looks like the `Execute` method gets the read lock, runs a callback and always releases the read lock via a finally block. However, for whatever reason the callback raise a InvalidConnectionException and the code try to `Reconnect()`. The `Reconnect()` will try to get the write lock in TryEnterWriteLock and ends up with System.Threading.LockRecursionException as read lock is already being hold by the current thread. I'm unable to see how could that possibly happen given the Finally block should release the read lock, unless the ExitReadLock is not doing what it suppose to do.

I've included the full class from the MassTransit source code and full stack trace.

```
public class DefaultConnectionPolicy : ConnectionPolicy
{
    readonly ConnectionHandler _connectionHandler;
    readonly TimeSpan _reconnectDelay;
    readonly ILog _log = Logger.Get(typeof(DefaultConnectionPolicy));
    readonly ReaderWriterLockSlim _connectionLock = new ReaderWriterLockSlim(LockRecursionPolicy.SupportsRecursion);

    public DefaultConnectionPolicy(ConnectionHandler connectionHandler)
    {
        _connectionHandler = connectionHandler;
        _reconnectDelay = 10.Seconds();
    }

    public void Execute(Action callback)
    {
        try
        {
            try
            {
                // wait here so we can be sure that there is not a reconnect in progress
                _connectionLock.EnterReadLock();
                callback();
            }
            finally
            {
                _connectionLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
        catch (InvalidConnectionException ex)
        {
            _log.Warn("Invalid Connection when executing callback", ex.InnerException);

            Reconnect();

            if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
            {
                _log.Debug("Retrying callback after reconnect.");
            }

            try
            {
                // wait here so we can be sure that there is not a reconnect in progress
                _connectionLock.EnterReadLock();
                callback();
            }
            finally
            {
                _connectionLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }

    void Reconnect()
    {
        if (_connectionLock.TryEnterWriteLock((int)_reconnectDelay.TotalMilliseconds/2))
        {
            try
            {
                if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
                {
                    _log.Debug("Disconnecting connection handler.");
                }
                _connectionHandler.Disconnect();

                if (_reconnectDelay > TimeSpan.Zero)
                    Thread.Sleep(_reconnectDelay);

                if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
                {
                    _log.Debug("Re-connecting connection handler...");
                }
                _connectionHandler.Connect();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                _log.Warn("Failed to reconnect, deferring to connection policy for reconnection");
                _connectionHandler.ForceReconnect(_reconnectDelay);
            }
            finally
            {
                _connectionLock.ExitWriteLock();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {
                _connectionLock.EnterReadLock();
                if (_log.IsDebugEnabled)
                {
                    _log.Debug("Waiting for reconnect in another thread.");
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                _connectionLock.ExitReadLock();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And the full stack trace

```
An exception was thrown during Send ---> System.Threading.LockRecursionException: Write lock may not be acquired with read lock held. This pattern is prone to deadlocks. Please ensure that read locks are released before taking a write lock. If an upgrade is necessary, use an upgrade lock in place of the read lock.
at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLockCore(TimeoutTracker timeout)
at System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim.TryEnterWriteLock(TimeoutTracker timeout)
at MassTransit.Transports.DefaultConnectionPolicy.Reconnect() in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Transports\DefaultConnectionPolicy.cs:line 75
at MassTransit.Transports.DefaultConnectionPolicy.Execute(Action callback) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Transports\DefaultConnectionPolicy.cs:line 53
at MassTransit.Transports.ConnectionPolicyChainImpl.Next(Action callback) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Transports\ConnectionPolicyChainImpl.cs:line 49
at MassTransit.Transports.ConnectionHandlerImpl`1.Use(Action`1 callback) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Transports\ConnectionHandlerImpl.cs:line 86
at MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq.OutboundRabbitMqTransport.Send(ISendContext context) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\Transports\MassTransit.Transports.RabbitMq\OutboundRabbitMqTransport.cs:line 51
at MassTransit.Transports.Transport.Send(ISendContext context) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Transports\Transport.cs:line 50
at MassTransit.Transports.Endpoint.Send[T](ISendContext`1 context) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Transports\Endpoint.cs:line 111
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MassTransit.Transports.Endpoint.Send[T](ISendContext`1 context) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Transports\Endpoint.cs:line 117
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Sinks.EndpointMessageSink`1.<Enumerate>b__0(IBusPublishContext`1 x) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Pipeline\Sinks\EndpointMessageSink.cs:line 45
at MassTransit.Pipeline.Sinks.OutboundConvertMessageSink`1.<>c__DisplayClass2.<>c__DisplayClass4.<Enumerate>b__1(ISendContext x) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Pipeline\Sinks\OutboundConvertMessageSink.cs:line 36
at MassTransit.ServiceBus.Publish[T](T message, Action`1 contextCallback) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\ServiceBus.cs:line 180
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at MassTransit.ServiceBus.Publish[T](T message, Action`1 contextCallback) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\ServiceBus.cs:line 207
at MassTransit.Context.BusObjectPublisherImpl`1.Publish(IServiceBus bus, Object message, Action`1 contextCallback) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\Context\BusObjectPublisherImpl.cs:line 30
at MassTransit.ServiceBus.Publish(Object message, Type messageType, Action`1 contextCallback) in z:\Builds\work\4ed32a1c3fc3f594\src\MassTransit\ServiceBus.cs:line 244
at CollectionHouse.MassTransit.Messaging.MassTransitMessageBus.PublishImmediate(Object message)
at CollectionHouse.MassTransit.Services.MassTransitPublisher.Publish(Object message)
at CollectionHouse.MicroBus.EventBroadcast.MessageBroadcastHandler.<Handle>d__6.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at Enexure.MicroBus.PipelineBuilder.<>c__DisplayClass7_0.<<GenerateNext>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at CollectionHouse.MicroBus.PipelineHandlers.LoggingHandler.<Handle>d__3.MoveNext()
```